setting a docker registry on nixos using systemd
I'm looking to establish a local Docker registry on a NixOS environment. I attempted to utilize the NixOS configuration option "services.dockerRegistry.enable = true" to achieve this, but encountered an issue. Upon attempting to push images, I received the
following error message:
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [localhost:5000/app-test-nix]
Get "http://localhost:5000/v2/": dial tcp [::1]:5000: connect: connection refused
To troubleshoot, I undertook the following steps:

Checked the logs of the registry-docker.service using systemctl status registry-docker.service, which revealed no relevant information.
Executed curl localhost:5000, resulting in an empty response and no pertinent entries in the service logs.
Subsequently, I attempted to manually run the Docker registry using the command docker run -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2.7, which proved successful. However, the issue persisted when I endeavored to encapsulate this command within a systemd service.
this fail (connection refused error message)
systemd.services.foo = {
    enable = true;
    description = "bar";
    unitConfig = {
      Type = "simple";
      # ...
    };
    serviceConfig = {
      ExecStart = "${pkgs.podman}/bin/podman run -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2.7";
      # ...
    };
    wantedBy = [ "multi-user.target" ];
    # ...
  };

this fail (connection refused error message)
     virtualisation.oci-containers = {
       backend = "docker";
       containers."registry" = {
         autoStart = true;
         image = "registry:2.7";
         ports = [
           "5555:5000"
         ];
       };
     };


this fail (connection refused error message)
services.dockerRegistry.enable = true;

this work
on my terminal just run:
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2.7
